# static generic method and subinterface?

Tags: java, generics, static-methods

I have an interface looks like this.

```java
public interface FieldEnum<T> {

    static <E extends Enum<E> & FieldEnum<T>, T> E valueOfRaw(
            final Class<E> type, final T raw) {
        for (final E enumConstant : type.getEnumConstants()) {
            if (Objects.equals(enumConstant.getRaw(), raw)) {
                return enumConstant;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("unknown raw: " + raw);
    }

    T getRaw();
}
```

When I extend it like this,

```java
public interface StringFieldEnum extends FieldEnum<String> {

}
```

Is it redundant to define following method in it?

```java
    static <E extends Enum<E> & StringFieldEnum> E valueOfRaw(
            final Class<E> type, final String raw) {
        return FieldEnum.valueOfRaw(type, raw);
    }
```

Comment: Did you try it with and without?  What was the result?

Comment: it indeed is, because you're not defining any different behaviour, so why not use `FieldEnum.valueOfRaw()` directly?